# how do i Display text from editText in activity 1 in textView in activity 2,

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

i followed the tutorial from android developers (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

This displays the edit text and creates a new textview which displays the text entered but. heres my problem.

i dont want my textview to be my layout as it is following that guide. i have created a new layout which includes a textview. i want to display the text from the first activity class into the textview on my new created activity. ive tried a few ways but keep getting fc

main activity

```
package com.jembe.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by ***** on 04/06/13.
 */
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
        /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

display my message activity

```
    package com.jembe.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.view1);


        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent;
        intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        //Display the message in textview
        tv.setText(message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are initializing TextView in `DisplayMessageActivity` before setting layout for Activity so initialize it inside onCreate after setContentView

```
TextView tv;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(R.layout.view1);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);  //<<< initialize here
        //.... your code here...
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for that. worked great. so simple too lol.